# customized transformerMixin with data labels in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm working on a small project where I'm trying to apply SMOTE "Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique", where my data is imbalanced ..

I created a customized transformerMixin for the SMOTE function ..

```
class smote(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print(X.shape, ' ', type(X)) # (57, 28)   <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
        print(len(y), ' ', type)     #    57      <class 'list'>
        smote = SMOTE(kind='regular', n_jobs=-1)
        X, y = smote.fit_sample(X, y)

        return X

    def transform(self, X):
        return X
```

---

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('posFeat1', featureVECTOR()),
        ('sca1', StandardScaler()),
        ('smote', smote()),
        ('classification', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', max_iter=1, random_state = 38, tol = None))
    ])
    model.fit(train_df, train_df['label'].values.tolist())
    predicted = model.predict(test_df)
```

I implemented the SMOTE on the FIT function because I don't want it to be applied on the test data ..

and unfortunately, I got this error:

```
     model.fit(train_df, train_df['label'].values.tolist())
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 362, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 520, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`fit()` mehtod should return self, not the transformed values. If you need the functioning only for train data and not test, then implement the `fit_transform()` method.

```
class smote(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print(X.shape, ' ', type(X)) # (57, 28)   <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
        print(len(y), ' ', type)     #    57      <class 'list'>
        self.smote = SMOTE(kind='regular', n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y)

        return self

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        self.fit(X, y)
        return self.smote.sample(X, y)

    def transform(self, X):
        return X
```

Explanation: On the train data (i.e. when `pipeline.fit()` is called) Pipeline will first try to call [`fit_transform()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/pipeline.py#L578) on the internal objects. If not found, then it will call `fit()` and `transform()` separately.

On the test data, only the `transform()` is called for each internal object, so here your supplied test data should not be changed.

**Update**: The above code will still throw error. 
You see, when you oversample the supplied data, the number of samples in `X` and `y` both change. But the pipeline will only work on the `X` data. It will not change the `y`. So either you will get error about unmatched samples to labels if I correct the above error. If by chance, the generated samples are equal to previous samples, then also the `y` values will not correspond to the new samples.

**Working solution**: Silly me.

You can just use the [Pipeline from the imblearn package](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) in place of scikit-learn Pipeline. It takes care automatically to `re-sample` when called `fit()` on the pipeline, and does not re-sample test data (when called `transform()` or `predict()`).

Actually I knew that imblearn.Pipeline handles `sample()` method, but was thrown off when you implemented a custom class and said that test data must not change. It did not come to my mind that thats the default behaviour.

Just replace

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

with

```
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

and you are all set. No need to make a custom class as you did. Just use original SMOTE. Something like:

```
random_state = 38
model = Pipeline([
        ('posFeat1', featureVECTOR()),
        ('sca1', StandardScaler()),

        # Original SMOTE class
        ('smote', SMOTE(random_state=random_state)),
        ('classification', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', max_iter=1, random_state=random_state, tol=None))
    ])
```

Comment: what u mean by: .sample(X, y) ? Also, why u didn't implement the smote inside the fit_transform rather than calling it !?

Comment: @Minion When you do `fit_sample()` you are joining two functions together, `fit()` and `sample()`. I have moved the `fit()` part to `fit()` and calling only `sample()` in `fit_transform()`. You can copy the whole `fit()` in there if you want. I did that just for code clarity.

Comment: ur code produces an error: File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (81,28) into shape (81)

Comment: @Minion Please provide your complete code and some data samples which produce the error. Edit the question to add the details.

Comment: its hard to do that, the code is very large and independent .. but I think the error is this line: return self.smote.sample(X,y) .. are you sure about it ?

Comment: @Minion Yes, I got the error. I will edit the answer to add the explanation.

Comment: @Minion. I have updated the answer with working solution.

Comment: What is the difference between fit_transform and fit_resample which one should i need to use?

Comment: @Kirushikesh In smote, fit_transform has no effect. It is simply there for compatibility with scikit-learn pipeline. Tell me more about what you want to do.