# Using Smote with Gridsearchcv in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, oversampling

I'm dealing with an imbalanced dataset and want to do a grid search to tune my model's parameters using scikit's gridsearchcv. To oversample the data, I want to use SMOTE, and I know I can include that as a stage of a pipeline and pass it to gridsearchcv.
My concern is that I think smote will be applied to both train and validation folds, which is not what you are supposed to do. The validation set should not be oversampled.
Am I right that the whole pipeline will be applied to both dataset splits? And if yes, how can I turn around this?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, but with [imblearn Pipeline](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/pipeline/plot_pipeline_classification.html).

You see, imblearn has its own Pipeline to handle the samplers correctly. I described this in [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49771602/3374996).

When called `predict()` on a `imblearn.Pipeline` object, it will skip the sampling method and leave the data as it is to be passed to next transformer.
You can confirm that by looking at the [source code here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/d9c8c64/imblearn/pipeline.py#L372):

```
        if hasattr(transform, "fit_sample"):
            pass
        else:
            Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
```

So for this to work correctly, you need the following:

```
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
model = Pipeline([
        ('sampling', SMOTE()),
        ('classification', LogisticRegression())
    ])

grid = GridSearchCV(model, params, ...)
grid.fit(X, y)
```

Fill the details as necessary, and the pipeline will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline work too for this purpose?

Comment: @EhsanM No. As I said above, sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline will not handle the `sample()` method of SMOTE, but imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline will.

Comment: @VivekKumar - Using `imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline` with `GridSearchCV` is resulting in an error. The `GridSearchCV` is not able to recognize the estimator's (`LogisticRegression`) parameters and tries to the param to the `Pipeline` itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal Please post a new question with your code and notify me

Comment: Hi @VivekKumar, I have created a new question with my implementation. Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815016/cross-validating-with-imblearn-pipeline-and-gridsearchcv

Comment: @agent18, I have updated the links. Thanks for notifying