# Cross Validating With Imblearn Pipeline And GridSearchCV

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline, imblearn

I'm trying to use the `Pipeline` class from `imblearn` and `GridSearchCV` to get the best parameters for classifying the imbalanced dataset. As per the answers mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245684/using-smote-with-gridsearchcv-in-scikit-learn/50245954?noredirect=1#comment103819811_50245954), I want to leave out resampling of the validation set and only resample the training set, which `imblearn`'s `Pipeline` seems to be doing. However, I'm getting an error while implementing the accepted solution. Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Below is my implementation:

```
def imb_pipeline(clf, X, y, params):

    model = Pipeline([
        ('sampling', SMOTE()),
        ('classification', clf)
    ])

    score={'AUC':'roc_auc', 
           'RECALL':'recall',
           'PRECISION':'precision',
           'F1':'f1'}

    gcv = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=params, cv=5, scoring=score, n_jobs=12, refit='F1',
                       return_train_score=True)
    gcv.fit(X, y)

    return gcv

for param, classifier in zip(params, classifiers):
    print("Working on {}...".format(classifier[0]))
    clf = imb_pipeline(classifier[1], X_scaled, y, param) 
    print("Best parameter for {} is {}".format(classifier[0], clf.best_params_))
    print("Best `F1` for {} is {}".format(classifier[0], clf.best_score_))
    print('-'*50)
    print('\n')
```

**params:**

```
[{'penalty': ('l1', 'l2'), 'C': (0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10)},
 {'n_neighbors': (10, 15, 25)},
 {'n_estimators': (80, 100, 150, 200), 'min_samples_split': (5, 7, 10, 20)}]
```

**classifiers:**

```
[('Logistic Regression',
  LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                     intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                     multi_class='warn', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
                     random_state=None, solver='warn', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                     warm_start=False)),
 ('KNearestNeighbors',
  KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
                       metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, n_neighbors=5, p=2,
                       weights='uniform')),
 ('Gradient Boosting Classifier',
  GradientBoostingClassifier(criterion='friedman_mse', init=None,
                             learning_rate=0.1, loss='deviance', max_depth=3,
                             max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                             min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                             min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                             min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100,
                             n_iter_no_change=None, presort='auto',
                             random_state=None, subsample=1.0, tol=0.0001,
                             validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=0,
                             warm_start=False))]
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter C for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('sampling',
                 SMOTE(k_neighbors=5, kind='deprecated',
                       m_neighbors='deprecated', n_jobs=1,
                       out_step='deprecated', random_state=None, ratio=None,
                       sampling_strategy='auto', svm_estimator='deprecated')),
                ('classification',
                 LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False,
                                    fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1,
                                    l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                                    multi_class='warn', n_jobs=None,
                                    penalty='l2', random_state=None,
                                    solver='warn', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                                    warm_start=False))],
         verbose=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`. """
```

Comment: Did you do a estimator.get_params().keys() ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean? How to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check this example how to use parameters with a Pipeline:
 - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-compare-reduction-py

Whenever using the pipeline, you will need to send the parameters in a way so that pipeline can understand which parameter is for which of the step in the list. For that it uses the name you provided during Pipeline initialisation.

In your code, for example:

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('sampling', SMOTE()),
        ('classification', clf)
    ])
```

To pass the parameter p1 to SMOTE you would use `sampling__p1` as a parameter, not `p1`.

You used `"classification"` as a name for your `clf` so append that to the parameters which are supposed to go to the `clf`.

Try:

```
[{'classification__penalty': ('l1', 'l2'), 'classification__C': (0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10)},
 {'classification__n_neighbors': (10, 15, 25)},
 {'classification__n_estimators': (80, 100, 150, 200), 'min_samples_split': (5, 7, 10, 20)}]
```

Make sure there are two underscores between the name and the parameter.

Comment: Btw, do you know how does the `Pipeline` exclude resampling the `KFold` cv while pairing `SMOTE` with `GridSeachCV`?

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal Thats how the imblearn pipeline is designed. It resamples only when `fit` is called, not when `predict` is called.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: i have a question: if i use gcv.best_estimator_ , after the procedure you just described, the model i get is trained with oversampled data?

Comment: thanks, I learnt something new today!