# Cross-Validating SMOTE with GridSearchCV in scikit-learn: Risk of data leakage?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, imblearn, smote

I'm trying to compare the information given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245684/using-smote-with-gridsearchcv-in-scikit-learn/77274835#77274835) on the interaction between `SMOTE` and `GridSearchCV`, in particular on the need not to oversample the validation dataset.

I’m using `Pipeline` from `imblearn.Pipeline`
I'm trying to set up a `Pipeline` that will still test - and therefore cross-validate ...) several sampling methods.

Is the approach correct or is there a risk of dataleak / oversampling of the validation dataset?

```py
model = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessor',StandardScaler()),
    ('sampling', SMOTE()),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
])

gridpsace=[{'preprocessor': [StandardScaler(), MinMaxScaler(), None],
            'sampling': [SMOTE(), None],
            'clf': [RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=4)], # Actual Estimator
            'clf__n_estimators': [100],
            'clf__max_depth': [10, None],
            'clf__class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
            }]

grid = GridSearchCV(model,
                    gridpsace,
                    scoring={'roc_auc': 'roc_auc', 'ftwo': scorer},
                    refit='roc_auc'
                    )

model_grid = grid.fit(X, y)
model_grid.cv_results_
```