# Outlier-Detection in Scikit-learn( Isolation Forest) in a pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have encountered the problem, as I can't use the Isolation Forest algorithm in the Sklearn pipeline. I am trying to predict the credit card default using the Kaggle Credit Card Fraud Detection dataset. I am trying to fix everything after data partitioning in order to avoid data leakage. (By using pipelines for every cross-validation as I get an almost 100% F1-score using Logistic Regression in K-fold cross-validation without using pipelines) Most of the machine learning algorithms can be used (Logistic Regression, Random Forest Classifier, etc) but not for some anomaly detection algorithms such as IsolationForest. I wondered how can I fit these anomaly detection algorithms inside the Pipelines. Thanks.

[Some details for X and Y (Y- 0 as a normal transaction, 1 as fraudulent transaction)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kozpu.png)

```
pipe =Pipeline([
    ('sc', StandardScaler()),
    ('smote', SMOTE()),
    ('IF', IsolationForest())
])

print(cross_val_score(pipe, X,Y, scoring='f1_weighted' ,cv=5))

# Result: [3.01179163e-06 3.53204982e-06 6.55363495e-06 3.51940600e-06 4.52981524e-06]
```

Comment: Please provide code snippets and sample data if needed, so other users can better understand your problem and suggest solutions.

Comment: Already add some details. Feel free to ask if it is not clear yet.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information, I would guess that your Pipeline import is from sklearn.pipelines. Just replace it with:

```
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

For further information [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770851/customized-transformermixin-with-data-labels-in-sklearn/49771602#49771602) helped me.